# Run Headless JsTestDriver?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, js-test-driver, headless-browser

Is there a way to use jsTestDriver in a headless state where it loads the browsers but does so headlessly (you can't see the browser) or it loads them minimized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to configure JsTestDriver to open the browser minimized. And you have to open the browsers because they run the JavaScript code.

You can try to create a virtual monitor and open the browser there.

Under linux you can use xvfb for this, for example

```
xvfb-run java -jar JsTestDriver-1.3.3d.jar --tests all --port 4224 --browser firefox chromium-browser --testOutput jsTests
```

should open the browser in a virtual window.

Answer (score 16):

You could use *PhantomJS* with *JSTestDriver*

First start *JStestdriver* in a *command prompt*:

```
java -jar JsTestDriver-1.3.5.jar  --port 9876 --captureConsole --runnerMode DEBUG
```

Download and use the *javascript* that is used to capture the *Phantom browser* [from here](https://github.com/larrymyers/js-test-driver-phantomjs/blob/master/phantomjs-jstd.js).

```
phantomjs.exe phantomjs-jstd.js
```

Output will be like:

```
 Wed Oct 31 2012 12:07:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time): Attempting (1) to load:

 http://localhost:9876/capture
```

Run your tests:

```
java -jar d:\Coding\lib\JsTestDriver-1.3.5.jar --tests all  --runnerMode DEBUG
```

Comment: This should be the chosen answer