# running jstd-maven-plugin tests without a browser

Tags: unit-testing, maven, htmlunit, js-test-driver, jasmine-maven-plugin

I've got *jsTestDriver* up and running, and I use *jstd-maven-plugin* to run the tests during a build.

The *plugin* needs a *browser* to be specified in order to work though, and I'd like to use something like *rhino* or *htmlunit* that won't actually launch a browser.

The *jasmine-maven-plugin* does this with *htmlunit*, and works quite well.

Is there a way to specify a headless browser for *jstd-maven-plugin*?

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons that I prefer JsTestDriver over other JavaScript testing frameworks, is that the tests are made on real browsers, and allows me to test on all the major browsers that consumes my application, and verify compatibility issues with older versions of IE for example.

If you prefer to run a complete headless JavaScript testing server, perhaps JsTestDriver is not your best choice. I think [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) is a very good alternative to achieve that. It uses PhantomJS, a scriptable headless WebKit engine to run the tests.

In my case, I have a complete headless server running an instance of JsTestDriver, and Other server whit a couple of virtual machines, with common SO/Browsers combinations (Windows/IE7; Windows/IE8; Linux/Firefox...), which have actual browsers connected to the headless JsTestDriver server. But if you don't need to use real browsers, the CasperJS alternative may be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

JsTestDriver need a browser to run the javascriptcode. So there is no way to run your tests without a browser.

There is a way to open the browser in a virtual monitor. This is described in this question:
[Run Headless JsTestDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144537/run-headless-jstestdriver/11162213#11162213)

Comment: The jstd-maven-plugin has a tag <browser></browser> which specifies the browser that will run the javascript.  My question is: instead of <browser>Firefox</browser>, can I do <browser>phantomJS</browser> (or something like that) so that nothing visible pops up but a browser is still loaded?

Answer (score -1):

JSTD maven plugin can be extended to run phanatomjs.

Comment: You didn't actually give any useful information about how to do this or where to find the solution.  -1